# Deploy Debian to the Artifactory repo from Jenkins

Tags: debian, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

How to deploy a Debian package from a Jenkins to the Artifactory Debian repo?
I used a command in the Jenkins Freestyle job:

```
curl -uUSER:PASS -XPUT "https://ARTIFACTORY_URL/REPO/pool/package.deb;deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64" -T ./package.deb
```

but in that case no reference is created between the Artifactory to the Jenkins. Meaning, we cannot link between the Jenkins build to the Artifact.
Next, we tried to use a pipeline and call it from the Freestyle after a Debian package is created. But again, there is no [wiki/support](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) about a Debian packages uploading using a DSL.
And seems that the [FileSpec](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs) doesn't support Debian packages.

How to pass architecture/distribution/component?

Did anyone have an experience with deploying Debian packages to the Artifactory? Sounds easy but still, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply with jfrog-cli:

`jfrog rt u --deb=<distribution>/<component>/<architecture> <debian-package> <debian-repo>/pool/<component>/<first-latter-of-package-name>/<package-name>/<debian-package>`

For example: uploading cassandra

`jfrog rt u --deb=bionic/main/all cassandra_1.2.3_all.deb debian-local/pool/main/c/cassandra/cassandra_1.2.3_all.deb`

Answer (score 9):

To upload debian packages to artifactory, you can use a fileSpec in your pipeline like that:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "YOUR_ARTIFACT_PATH",
      "target": "https://ARTIFACTORY_URL/REPO/pool/",
      "props": "deb.distribution=xenial;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=amd64"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: do you know how to add gpg signing to the Release file within the Debian Artifactory repo?

Comment: You can follow [GPG Signing](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/GPG+Signing) and recalculate indexes. Everytimes a package is pushed on the repository, he will be signed.